# Prometheus target showing down

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, prometheus-java

Please note: my prometheus is running using ubuntu terminal and my springboot application is running on windows.  Seems like my ubuntu is not able to connect with the localhost of windows.

I have created springboot metrics using "actuator" and my metrics are being exposed at "http/localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus".

My application.yml configuration in my springboot application looks like this:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus


The configuration file of prometheus i.e. prometheus.yml is as below:
scrape_configs:
# The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from 
this config.
  - job_name: "services"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
```

Despite this configuration, i see "target" as down in prometheus interface. It says

```
Get "http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Why is prometheus not able to pick the metrics at `localhost`?

Comment: were you able to solve the problem and how?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
In this case, my application used Basic Auth to access any link. So, I needed to add these lines to my configuration file :

```
basic_auth:
      username: "username" # username with permission on the database
      password: "password" # password compatible with username
```

All credit to [Lucas Ribeiro Barzotto](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCixiZz8NemCUzX1MOnpAnrQ) who helped by comments on [devdojo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKPTqzIdcPA&list=PL62G310vn6nFBIxp6ZwGnm8xMcGE3VA5H&index=50)

Answer (score 0):

First try this;

The configuration file of `prometheus` i.e. `prometheus.yml` is as below:

scrape_configs:

The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from
this config.

```
- job_name: "services"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["host.docker.internal:8080"]
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
```

When you try this if you get this error again

```
'[Prometheus] Get "http://host.docker.internal:8080/metrics": dial tcp: lookup host.docker.internal on' error 

Please enter ip directly, not localhost, in the destination address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```